# Can I sell a rhino horn carving?

Tags: united-states, pennsylvania, animals

Suppose that a son inherits a rhino horn carving from his father. Assuming that the father acquired the horn without violating any laws that were in force at the time it was acquired.

Can the son legally sell the horn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhino horn [cannot](https://www.fws.gov/international/pdf/factsheet-can-i-sell-it.pdf) be sold across state lines:

> **Rhino horn:** Generally cannot be sold in
> interstate or international commerce.
> Consult the Service for limited
> exceptions. Import or export requires
> a permit. Sale of items within a State
> allowed unless restricted by “use
> after import” limitations associated
> with items imported after the listing
> of the species under CITES or unless
> prohibited under State law.

Pennsylvania has a proposed [bill](https://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/billInfo/billInfo.cfm?sYear=2017&sInd=0&body=H&type=B&bn=248) banning the sale of rhino horn but it is not yet law.